# Did I Miss All the Chapter 3 Side Quests?

Tags: the-witcher-2

So I entered Loc Muinne with Iorveth, and my quest directive basically said to find Phillipa, so I did that immediately.  My assumption was that the city was hostile to me and I needed to more or less sneak around.

I am having trouble with the golem in the Spellbreaker quest, and because of this have looked at some walkthrough help sites.  I couldn't help but notice some text that implied that I am on the path to the final battle.

Can I still do side quests after the Spellbreaker quest, or am I locked on a path to the end game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes **you can**,however it will be your **last chance** do do so.
After you complete "Spellbreaker" quest you will unlock "A summit of mages" quest and once you start "**A summit of mages**" your remaining quests will be failed.

[Walkthrough(source)](http://guides.gamepressure.com/thewitcher2assassinsofkings/guide.asp?ID=11436)